# Get value of JSON object in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following code I would use in C#:

```
    var tokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenJsonString);

    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
    var firstItem = jsonResult["data"][0];
```

However, I have a VB.NET client, and I have no idea how to translate it. I have tried different online tools without a result.

I have a JSON response like this:

```
"{\"token\":\"1edd6006-678a-4e6a-ab65-4fa60efa8632\"}"
```

And I just want the value of the token. In VB.NET ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Dim tokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenJsonString)

 Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(jsonString)
 Dim firstItem = jsonResult.Item("data").Item(0)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Example JSON :

```
{
  "fuits": [
    
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "cars": [
        {
          "skoda": "2Lacks",
          "maruti": 400000,
          "neon": "3 Lacks",
          
        },
        {
          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If you want to acess the value for `skoda` in the above example json in `VB.NET` using `JObject.Parse`, Write it as :

```
Dim wallet As String = jsonobject("vehicles")(0)("cars")(0)("skoda").ToString()
```

Now you have `2Lacks` in `wallet`!

Answer (score 0):

Chosen awnser gives you the row { "token":"1edd6006-678a-4e6a-ab65-4fa60efa8632" }
Had the same problem and to get exactly the value of the token you can do:

```
Dim firstItem = jsonResult.Item("data").Item(0).Value(Of String)("token")
```

Outputs: "1edd6006-678a-4e6a-ab65-4fa60efa8632"

Hope it helps